# iOS Can't change UIBarButtonItem image properly

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm having a problem when I try to change a UINavigationBar's "back" button custom icon. To achieve such a thing, I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem* leftBtn;
    UIImage* botonVolverImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boton_volver.png"]; 

    leftBtn = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    leftBtn.image = botonVolverImg;
}
```

But, when the view appears, you see this:

[a busy cat http://www.timotteo.com.ar/boton.png](http://www.timotteo.com.ar/boton.png)

(You can see that the old button still appears at the back, plus the image I chose looks a bit streched)

I've been changing the **imageInsets** property, but that doesn't seem to work. I've also been reading the forum around, but couldn´t find the exact solution.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: if you're just using text & string titles, couldn't you just set the `title` property on your UIBarButtonItem?  Seems like a lot less hassle to me.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDautermann that seems a good idea, But my customer wants THAT specific image, so I have to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To supplement Mark's answer, if your customer is requiring you to support iOS 4, you could create a `UIButton` that looks exactly how your customer wants it to (ie, just that image), and then use `UIBarButton`'s `initWithCustomView` method to create your own back button. You can then have that button trigger `popViewController` or whatever appropriate action you need.

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The `image` property for `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't correspond to the background image, only an image that provides additional context. If you're targeting 5.0+, your best bet would be to use `-setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` to set a background for the bar button item.

Comment: In this case since it's specifically the 'back' button we're talking about, `setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` may be a better choice.
`

Comment: This seems a cool solution, but sadly the version of xcode/ios I have to use (customer's requirement) doesn´t seem to support such a method (I'm talking about setBackButtonBackgroundImage)